# Bootstrap + Responsive: Change multi column table to single column for mobile? (with images)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with my multi column table form on mobile where the input fields are squeezed when the browser is small.

It looks like this on a desktop:

[image]

My page is already responsive, but when I squeeze the browser the form looks like this:

[image]

My HTML looks like this (I'm using Rails, so please excuse anything that looks weird. The HTML is still there):

```
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 hero-feature payment_info">
            <%= form_for @payment_info, url: update_billing_checkout_path, remote: true, method: :put do |f| %>
            <table class="table table-bordered tbl-checkout">
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_first_name, "First Name" %></td>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_first_name, class: "form-control" %>
                        </td>
                        <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_last_name, "Last Name" %></td>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_last_name, class: "form-control" %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_street_address, "Street Address" %></td>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_street_address, class: "form-control" %>
                        </td>
                        <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_street_address2, "Apt/Suite" %></td>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_street_address2, class: "form-control" %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                        <textarea name="" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        </tr> -->
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_city, "City" %></td>
                            <td>
                                <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_city, class: "form-control" %>
                            </td>
                            <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_state_id, "State" %></td>
                            <td>
                                <%= f.collection_select :shipping_address_state_id, State.all, :id, :short_name, class: "form-control" %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_zip_code, "Zip Code" %></td>
                            <td>
                                <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_zip_code, class: "form-control" %> 
                            </td>
                            <td><%= f.label :shipping_address_phone_number, "Phone Number" %></td>
                            <td>
                                <%= f.text_field :shipping_address_phone_number, class: "form-control" %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- <tr>
                            <td>Comment</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                            <textarea name="" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </td>
                            </tr> -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

==UPDATE==

Per MaryMelody's request, adding:

```
    td {
        display: table-row;
    }
```

Makes it look like this and also affects all my `td`'s:

[image]

Comment: @MaryMelody sorry I'm a backend guy so I didn't know about that. How would I implement that?

Comment: could you provide a working demo on [bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/uKygUey5DZ)?

Comment: Sure hold on @MaryMelody !

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/uKygUey5DZ#

Comment: try to use `display: table-row;` to `.table > tbody > tr td` in your project...

Comment: That made everything ugly. I updated the question to show a screenshot of what happened

Comment: are you using it only for small screen size like 480px - `@media (max-width: 480px){.table > tbody > tr td{display: table-row;}}` and you could use `padding` or `margin` around the `td` to makes it look better... lol

Comment: Nice!!! It looks decent enough to implement. Do you know how I would make it a bit wider so that the input fits the whole width?

Comment: could you show me screenshot? and please use that site to upload a screenshot and comment the url and mark it as the way what you want if possible - http://tinypic.com/

Comment: @MaryMelody it looks exactly like the last image from above. The inputs are squeezed a bit

Comment: here: http://www.bootply.com/Wu4WdQGMP9 sorry i thought the one i pasted was updated

Comment: check it out - http://www.bootply.com/qU1izE4ynl **or** full screen demo - http://www.bootply.com/render/qU1izE4ynl

Comment: omg you're the best!!!1 make it an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by CSS `@media` queries for small screens.

### Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/qU1izE4ynl)

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .table > tbody > tr td {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%
    }
    .table > tbody > tr td input {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```